# Asio two way communication with peristence socket

Tags: c++, boost-asio

I have this requirement where my app have to connect to another app via sockets and will have to maintain persistent connection for quiet long time. My app will be a TCP client and the other is a TCP server. My app will send commands and the server will respond accordingly.

The problem am facing right now is how to read the whole data from server a string and return for app which will issue the next command. Reading synchronously (with `asio::read`) looked like a good option up until I observed socket hanging up until I terminate the server. Looking at the documentation I found that the library is correctly working.

> his function is used to read a certain number of bytes of data from a stream. The call will block until one of the following conditions is true:
>    1. The supplied buffers are full. That is, the bytes transferred is equal to the sum of the buffer sizes.
>   2. An error occurred.

The problem is I don't know correct buffer size as the response from the server varies. So If I put a too small buffer it returns fine but missing some data. If I put too big it will hang forever until server quits.

So I thought I would do the async reading. It works only once and I don't know how to make it fetch data until whole data it read.

here is the relevant async code

```
#define ASIO_STANDALONE 1

#include <iostream>
#include <asio.hpp>

int main()
{
    asio::io_context context;
    size_t reply_length;
    size_t length = 1024;
    std::vector<char> buffer;

    //create socket
    asio::ip::tcp::socket socket(context);
    socket.connect(asio::ip::tcp::endpoint(asio::ip::address::from_string("127.0.0.1"), 8088));

    std::string dataOut = "list --files"; //some command to write
    std::error_code error;

    asio::write(socket, asio::buffer(dataOut), error);
    if (!error)
    {
        std::cout << "Receiving...!" << std::endl;
        buffer.resize(length);
        asio::async_read(socket, asio::buffer(buffer), [&buffer, &context](const asio::error_code &ec, std::size_t bytes_transferred) {
            std::copy(buffer.begin(), buffer.end(), std::ostream_iterator<char>(std::cout, ""));
            std::cout << "\nRead total of:" << bytes_transferred << "\n";
            context.run();
        });
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "send failed: " << error.message() << std::endl;
    }

    context.run();
}
```

Searching didn't help much solving my issue.

So my question is, how can I read all the data in a persistent socket with asio? Am not using boost.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to loop `async_read` calls. If you don't want your client to hang on read operation you can define the smallest possible buffer i.e. `1` byte.

Define function which takes *socket*, *buffer* and two additional parameters according to async_read's handler signature, and this function calls itself with `async_read` to make the loop of `async_read` calls - it reads until some error occures:

```
void onRead (
    asio::ip::tcp::socket&    socket,
    std::array<char,1>&       buf,
    const system::error_code& ec, 
    std::size_t               bytes)
{
    if (ec)
    {
        if (ec == asio::error::eof && bytes == 1)
            std::cout << buf[0];
        return;
    }

    std::cout << buf[0];   
    asio::async_read(socket,asio::buffer(buf), 
        std::bind(onRead, std::ref(socket), std::ref(buf),
          std::placeholders::_1, // error code
          std::placeholders::_2)); // transferred bytes
}
```

and the changes in `main`:

```
std::array<char,1> buf;
asio::write(socket, asio::buffer(dataOut), error);

if (!error)
{
    std::cout << "Receiving...!" << std::endl;               

    asio::async_read(socket, asio::buffer(buf), 
        std::bind(onRead, std::ref(socket), std::ref(buf),
         std::placeholders::_1,
         std::placeholders::_2));

    context.run();
}
else
{
    std::cout << "send failed: " << error.message() << std::endl;
}
```

(I am using Boost, so you should replace `system::error_code` on `asio::error_code`).

Comment: Great explanation and code. let me play around to be sure I understand everything. I'll be back!

Comment: @StefanoMtangoo no problem, glad to help :)